# 'RLMException', reason: 'Object type 'User' is not managed by the Realm

Tags: objective-c, realm

After updating to realm version 3.0.2 I am getting the following error:
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object type 'User' is not managed by the Realm. If using a custom `objectClasses` / `objectTypes` array in your configuration, add `User` to the list of `objectClasses` / `objectTypes`." while I am adding a new object like that:

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
User *user = [[User alloc] init];
user.username = self.txtUsername.text;
user.password = self.txtPassword.text;
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm addObject:user];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

And that's how I am configuring the realm:

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
    // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
    config.schemaVersion = 6;

    // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with a
    // schema version lower than the one set above
    config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {

    };

    // Move the realm database to the shared group
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *currentRelamUrl = config.fileURL;

    NSURL *appGroupUrl = [fileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"*****"];
    NSURL *realmUrl = [appGroupUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"default.realm"];

    //Moves the realm to the new location if it hasn't been done previously
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:currentRelamUrl.path] &&
        ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:realmUrl.path]) {

        NSError *error = nil;
        [fileManager moveItemAtURL:currentRelamUrl
                             toURL:realmUrl
                             error:&error];

        config.fileURL = realmUrl;

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error moving realm file url %@", error);
        }
    } else if (![config.fileURL.path isEqualToString:realmUrl.path]) {
        config.fileURL = realmUrl;
    }

    config.objectClasses = @[ChatMessage.class, [User class]
                             ];



    // Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
    [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];



    // Now that we've told Realm how to handle the schema change, opening the file
    // will automatically perform the migration
    [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

    return config;
```

Comment: Nothing in your code stands out as obviously erroneous. Would you be willing to create a reproduction case, then file an issue at our GitHub issue tracker? (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues)

Comment: My code works like a charm with older version of Realm(1.2), after the update to 3.0.2 these errors appear, all my realm request failed!:(

Comment: I understand your problem (since you stated it in your question originally), but the fact of the matter remains that the best way to get timely assistance and to respect SO's community conventions is to file a new ticket at the GitHub issue tracker and enclose a reproduction case.